# Unmatched rows with values from both tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, join

I have two tables T1:

```
+----+-----+--------------------+----------+
| ID | emp |     manager        |     proj |
+----+-----+--------------------+----------+
|  1 | Sam |     Tom            |       aa |
|  1 | Sam |     Tom            |       bb |
|  1 | Sam |     Tom            |       cc |
|  1 | Sam |     Tom            |       dd |
+----+-----+--------------------+----------+
```

Table T2:

```
+--------+---------+--------+-----------+
| Course |  Type   | proj   | Category  |
+--------+---------+--------+-----------+
| XYZ    |     NEW |     aa |    a      |
| DWE    |     OLD |     bb |    b      |
| RTY    |     OLD |     ii |    c      |
| UIO    |     NEW |     gg |    d      |
+--------+---------+--------+-----------+
```

OUTPUT:

```
+-----------+-----+----------+--------+---------+---------+----------+
|    ID     | emp |  manager |  proj  | Course  |  Type   | Category |
+-----------+-----+----------+--------+---------+---------+----------+
|         1 | Sam |  Tom     |     ii |     RTY |     OLD |     c    |
|         1 | Sam |  Tom     |     gg |     UIO |     NEW |     d    |
+-----------+-----+----------+--------+---------+---------+----------+
```

I have one common col proj, table 1 has the proj done by the emp, table2 has both proj done and not done by emp with additional fields. I want to get all the unmatched rows from table2 but with the attributes from table 1 as above. Can someone help with a SQL query to do this??

Comment: Is that output what you want or what you currently get? If its not the desired can you add that in?

Comment: What's the logic by which employee `Sam` and manager `Tom` are being brought into the expected output?  That information comes from the first table, but, by definition, there is no relation to that table from the second table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  edited it to make it more readable now, hope that works

Comment: @TomC the output I want

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the only common col is proj, and whatever is againts sam for manager flows to the output, basically I need the not done projects with all attributes of SAM as is from table1

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I don't really understand how to get rows from table 1.

Comment: Is there a such thing as foreign keys in this table? Is there a source for "ID"-- Ie, what table does that come from (what table has that ID as its primary key)? Also, are their other columns in these tables you're not mentioning. The design at first glance looks like a hot mess

Comment: @my_way I think your database model is not 3NF. Table 1 has columns that should be in two separate tables. Also, can you add the foreign  keys?

Comment: @JoeLove love no the only common cols is proj, yes the source data is messed up and hence I am unable to get data from table 1

Comment: From your example, you are getting every distinct employee from T1. Is that what you want? So if there are 5 employees you would get every unmatched project with every employee?

Comment: The database model is too screwed up. Voting to close.

Comment: @TomC yes exactly every employee with their details from table1 attached to the undone projs from table 2

Comment: @TheImpaler Constraints (FKs, NFs) are not needed to query. What is needed is what output & input table rows say about the situation. Of course, the input might be insufficient for the desired output, but that's not a matter of constraints.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Constraints (including FKs) are not needed to query. Any two tables can be meaningfully joined. Here both tables' rows state something about a project, so a row of a join of them says something about a project from each. It needn't be the case that, say, a project participating with some values in one table/relationship/association implies that it participates with some values in another--which would be the case when a FK holds.

Comment: @philipxy Great comment.  But then why haven't you posted an answer if the question clearly is answerable?

Comment: Do you really mean that there is just one employee involved here & both tables only have the data for just that employee? For each table, what exactly does a row say by being it?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I criticized some misleading comments; answerability is a separate question. The post isn't clear re "unmatched" but taking the obvious meaning of different proj it's answerable because the result is described in terms of *just "unmatched" & table values*--not in terms of table meanings. But even if "unmatched" involved application notions, table 2 is for the same employee as table 1, so we can join them for data re that employee. (Per "what input & output rows say"--not constraints.) But I suspect the asker wants inputs re many employees so I asked for clarity & a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
with a as (
select T2.* from T1 right join T2 
on T1.proj=T2.proj
where T1.proj is null) ,

 b as (select T1.id, T1.emp, t1.manager from T1 left join T2 
on T1.proj=T2.proj
group by T1.id, T1.emp, t1.manager,T2.proj
having T2.proj is null)

select * from a cross join b
```

Comment: I don't think this is right. He wants an anti-join, not an outer join.

Comment: @TheImpaler you can suggest how the design can be improved rather than choosing to close! I can modufy table1 but not table 2

Comment: @my_way hope you got the output after my modification

Answer (score 0):

```
select e.ID, e.emp, e.manager, t2.proj, t2.Course, t2.Type as Name, t2.Category
from t2
cross join (select distinct ID, emp, manager from T1) e
where not exists(select * from t1 where t1.prog=t2.proj)
```

Comment: I am using oracle and it gives me a missing keyword error, do we need to specify the join condition 'on' ?

Comment: Yes you are correct - should be a cross join. I've updated the query.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT  tbl.ID, tbl.emp, tbl.manager, t2.proj, t2.Course, t2.Type as Name, t2.Category
FROM
(
SELECT t2.ID, t2.emp, t2.manager
FROM Table2 t2 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table1 t1 WHERE t1.proj = t2.proj) 
) tbl 
CROSS APPLY Table1 t1

Comment: Please read the edit help re formatting code & look at the formatted version of your answer & click edit to edit it.